# How can i allow users to give different responses to content types other than comments?

Tags: nodes, comments

How can i allow users to give different responses to content types other than comments? for example if i want users to be able give blog posts a "like" or "thumbs up/down" or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could try any of these modules (with quotes included from their project pages):

- [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar):

  > ... adds a clean, attractive voting widget to nodes and comments and any entity.
- [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate):

  > ... provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments ("*The cck model for voting with Drupal*").
- [Vote Up/Down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down):

  > ... allows votes on some Drupal entities and provides the base for implementing votes on other entities.

Comment: Don't forget the https://drupal.org/project/flag module as well :)